# How can I use && in if in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, boolean, if-statement

I tried the following && conditional for my if statement and I get a "bad range" error:

```
<% if (from_today(contact, call.days) == 0..7) && (show_status(contact, call) == 'no status') %>
```

Why and how can I fix it?  The only other way I could do it was to have a second nested if statement and break it apart...not pretty :(

Comment: The problem is the `if (condition) && (condition)`, ruby's parser is stopping after the first condition as you don't have an explicit begin to your if statement. By changing it to `if (condition && condition)` or `if ((condition) && (condition))` it should solve your problem (Dolph Mathews answer)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<% if (from_today(contact, call.days) == (0..7) && show_status(contact, call) == 'no status') %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try putting the `0..7` in parentheses. The `&&`is not your problem here.